# How to efficiently find pattern in one column and assign a corresponding value to another column in a list of data frames?

Tags: r

I have a list of 15 data frames with each 13 columns (time + 6 stations with each 3 layers) and 172 rows. I want to collapse those columns (observations at stations) in basically two columns (one for station and one for observation) by applying a function over the whole list. Here I use gather from `tidyr`. In addition, I want to find a pattern (upper, middle or lower layer) in one of the columns and assign a new value (depth) in a new column. For this I use `ddply` from `plyr` and grep. My problem is that it is veryyyy slow. I guess I created a bottleneck with my limited R knowledge. So where is the bottleneck and how to improve it?

an example:

```
  data <- list(a = data.frame(time = (1:180), alpha.upper = sample(1:180),
               beta.middle = sample(1:180), gamma.lower = sample(1:180)), 
               b = data.frame(time(1:180), alpha.upper = sample(1:180), 
               beta.middle = sample(1:180), gamma.lower = sample(1:180)))

> data
$a
    time alpha.upper beta.middle gamma.lower
 1      1         133         179          99
 2      2         175         147          56
 3      3         169           9          24
 4      4         116         129          75
 5      5          92          65          65
 6      6         141          73          49
$b
    time alpha.upper beta.middle gamma.lower
1      1         111           2          89
2      2          84          81         159
3      3          93          82          84
4      4          44          58         125
5      5          31          33         131
6      6           1         120          63
```

my code is:

```
> data2<-lapply(data, function(x) {
               x<-gather(x,stn,value,-time)
               x<-arrange(x,time)
               x<-ddply(x,c("time","stn","value"), function(x) {
                 if (grepl(".upper",x$stn) == TRUE)
                 {
                   x$depth<-1
                   return(x)
                 }
                 if (grepl(".lower",x$stn) == TRUE)
                 {
                   x$depth<-3
                   return(x)
                 }
                 if (grepl(".middle",x$stn) == TRUE)
                 {
                   x$depth<-2
                   return(x)
                 }
               })
               return(x)
             })
```

the result should be:

```
> data2
$a
    time         stn value depth
1      1 alpha.upper   111     1
2      1 beta.middle     2     2
3      1 gamma.lower    89     3
4      2 alpha.upper    84     1
5      2 beta.middle    81     2
6      2 gamma.lower   159     3
$b
1      1 alpha.upper    38     1
2      1 beta.middle   151     2
3      1 gamma.lower    93     3
4      2 alpha.upper    61     1
5      2 beta.middle    56     2
6      2 gamma.lower    66     3
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `set.seed` here as it is impossible reproduce results from `sample` without it. Try running `sample(10); sample(10); sample(10)` and see if you get same results each time.

Comment: well, I didnt care for values themselves. That is just for illustration. The numeric values can be anything. But I get what you mean. I am just interested in the efficiency of the restructuring.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's reproduce your data.

```
dataa <- read.table(text =
"time alpha.upper beta.middle gamma.lower
1 133 179 99
2 175 147 56
3 169 9 24
4 116 129 75
5 92 65 65
6 141 73 49", header = T, sep = " ")

datab <- read.table(text =
"time alpha.upper beta.middle gamma.lower
1 1 111 2 89
2 2 84 81 159
3 3 93 82 84
4 4 44 58 125
5 5 31 33 131
6 6 1 120 63", header = T, sep = " ")

mydata <- list(a = dataa, b = datab)
# $a
#   time alpha.upper beta.middle gamma.lower
# 1    1         133         179          99
# 2    2         175         147          56
# 3    3         169           9          24
# 4    4         116         129          75
# 5    5          92          65          65
# 6    6         141          73          49
# $b
#   time alpha.upper beta.middle gamma.lower
# 1    1         111           2          89
# 2    2          84          81         159
# 3    3          93          82          84
# 4    4          44          58         125
# 5    5          31          33         131
# 6    6           1         120          63
```

Here I named the variable `mydata` because there is a fuction `data` in standart package `utils` and it's better not to use this name for a variable.

As far as I've got it, you need to make every `data.frame` of the list from "wide" to "long" form. You can use `gather` from `tidyr` package and in my opinion it's a clever choise, but for this situation I show how we can get the same result with basic R tools.

```
rebuilddf <- function(df)
{ # first of all see the difference between rep(1:3, each = 3) and rep(1:3, times = 3)

  res_df <- data.frame(
    time = rep(df$time, each = 3),# first column of new data.frame -
                                  # we repeat each time mark 3 times
                                  # as we know that there are exactly 3
                                  # observations for single time: upper, middle, lower

    stn = rep(colnames(df)[-1], times = nrow(df)), # second column
                                  # fill it with words "alpha.upper",
                              # "beta.middle", "gamma.lower" which are colnames(df)[-1]
                                  # repeated nrow(df) times 

    value = as.vector(t(as.matrix(df[,-1]))) ) # 
                                  # numbers of 2:4 columns of our data.frame are
                                  # transposed and then arranged in a vector
                                  # the result is like reading it row by row
  # to understand what's happening with the matrix you can try this code
  # m <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 4)
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  # [1,]    1    5    9   13   17
  # [2,]    2    6   10   14   18
  # [3,]    3    7   11   15   19
  # [4,]    4    8   12   16   20
  # as.vector(t(m))
  # 1  5  9 13 17  2  6 10 14 18  3  7 11 15 19  4  8 12 16 20

  # after that we add column "depth"
  # as I got it, we need 1 for "upper", 2 for "middle" and 3 for "lower"
  # we make it with the help of two nested ifelse functions
  res_df <- transform(res_df, depth = ifelse(stn == "alpha.upper", 1, 
                                             ifelse(stn == "beta.middle", 2, 3)) )
  return(res_df)
}
```

If the names of columns are not always the same, and only the end of the name is invariant we can modify condition for `depth` as follows:

```
res_df <- 
  transform(res_df, 
            depth = ifelse(rev(strsplit(stn, "[.]")[[1]])[1] == "upper", 
                           1, 
                           ifelse(rev(strsplit(stn, "[.]")[[1]])[1] == "middle", 2, 3)
                           ) )
# we work with 
# rev(strsplit(stn, "[.]")[[1]])[1]
# it may be "upper", "middle" or "lower"
# here we split character string of form "some.name1.upper" or
# "some.other.colname.lower" by every dot in text, then take 
# the first from end part of the string (rev does reversing order)
```

You may also modify the condition and use `grepl`, but I believe it will be faster with `strsplit`.

When we've finished with our `rebuilddf` function let's watch what it does.

```
lapply(mydata, rebuilddf)

# $a
#    time         stn value depth
# 1     1 alpha.upper   133     1
# 2     1 beta.middle   179     2
# 3     1 gamma.lower    99     3
# 4     2 alpha.upper   175     1
# 5     2 beta.middle   147     2
# 6     2 gamma.lower    56     3
# 7     3 alpha.upper   169     1
# 8     3 beta.middle     9     2
# 9     3 gamma.lower    24     3
# 10    4 alpha.upper   116     1
# 11    4 beta.middle   129     2
# 12    4 gamma.lower    75     3
# 13    5 alpha.upper    92     1
# 14    5 beta.middle    65     2
# 15    5 gamma.lower    65     3
# 16    6 alpha.upper   141     1
# 17    6 beta.middle    73     2
# 18    6 gamma.lower    49     3
# 
# $b
#    time         stn value depth
# 1     1 alpha.upper   111     1
# 2     1 beta.middle     2     2
# 3     1 gamma.lower    89     3
# 4     2 alpha.upper    84     1
# 5     2 beta.middle    81     2
# 6     2 gamma.lower   159     3
# 7     3 alpha.upper    93     1
# 8     3 beta.middle    82     2
# 9     3 gamma.lower    84     3
# 10    4 alpha.upper    44     1
# 11    4 beta.middle    58     2
# 12    4 gamma.lower   125     3
# 13    5 alpha.upper    31     1
# 14    5 beta.middle    33     2
# 15    5 gamma.lower   131     3
# 16    6 alpha.upper     1     1
# 17    6 beta.middle   120     2
# 18    6 gamma.lower    63     3
```

I want to believe it's your desired output, though in the question you show us in `a` data.frame numbers from `b` and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Thanks for the try! But did it work for you? I only get a error about the wrong number of dimensions. Besides, i dont understand your code.

Comment: Yes it works fine without any errors. I edited my answer with detailed explanations of code